# c# linq - set based operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an IQueryable list which has 5 fields. 4 of which comes from DB.
The 5th field has to be assigned from code using a join Statement(of couple other tables which are not foreign key referenced to this table).

The query looks like this.

`Profile` Class the following fields.

```
Id, Name, Username, Email, Product
```

The product field is not in DB. It has to be populated in C# code using the following query.

```
  var resultSet = (from a in Profiles
                   join _b_ in billingPeriodIncludes
                   on a.Id equals (int?) _b_._cbp.BundleId into b_
                   from _b in b_.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where a.Product != null
                   select new
                   { 
                     a,
                     Product = (_b != null && _b._p != null) ? (_b._p) : a.Product
                   }
```

The query gives me a combination of Profile and a Product. Now I loop through each profile and assign each product to its profile.

Could someone help me in doing a direct set based assign of the products to profile?

something like this,(not working)

```
var q1 = (from a in Profiles
          join _b_ in billingPeriodIncludes
          on a.Id equals (int?) _b_._cbp.BundleId into b_
          from _b in b_.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select
          //Assign products to the set. Query the set in a separate query.
          a.Product = (_b != null && _b._p != null) ? (_b._p) : a.Product
          );
var q2 = from _q2 in q1 select _q2;
```

Comment: It's impossible. The way you do it is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var resultSet = (from a in Profiles
                 join _b_ in billingPeriodIncludes
                 on a.Id equals (int?) _b_._cbp.BundleId into b_
                 from _b in b_.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where a.Product != null
                 select new Profiles
                 { 
                    Id = a.Id,
                    Name = a.Name,
                    Username = a.Username,
                    Email = a.Email,
                    Product = (_b != null && _b._p != null) ? (_b._p) : a.Product
                 };
```

You can directly bind the `Profiles` object, instead of `anonymous` types.

Comment: Though this works, Profiles class might grow in columns. If a new column is added, it might get missed out here.

Comment: @Raghav - If `Profiles` class will grow, its going to be available in the query too right? since we are joining the `Profiles` type only. So what you are saying is incorrect.

Comment: U r right Rahul. But Profiles Class is widely used across. When a new column is added, the value of the column should be assigned here. If its missed here, it would lead to null for default column. The query is perfect, am just looking for something like "select * from from" in the select part.

Comment: Okay but I don't think its possible with a left join, cz if will select only object `a`, it will result in a runtime error.